# PF_UNIX socket blocks after sending twelve packets

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I've never encountered such thing before in my life.

I've created some simple uds socket in my C program, ( I'll show my example with python but it's the same syscalls / API called eventually )

and the weirdest thing happened

```
from socket import *

a = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM)

a.connect("SomePathAlreadyBounded")

for i in range(0,13):
   print(str(i))
   a.send("hey")
```

this prints up to 12 and then starts blocking... and unblocks only when the server reads from socket buffer.... I've already tried playing around with the `setsockopt` option under `SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` yet no success

has anyone encountered this sort of problem before? if so how do I fix it.... I want to but a big emphasis on the fact that `send` starts blocking exclusively after 12 packets were sent... regardless of their size...

Comment: @molbdnilo lol, no it's UDS, read the question first

Comment: OK, but the question remains: why don't you post the code you're having a problem with?

Comment: I cannot test it now, but Linux man page documents some parameters under `/proc/sys/net/core/` in man page of unix(7). But I'm afraid you will have to tweak some kernel parameters to extend the limit, and anyway, you could not remove it completely.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'd love it if you could test it somehow and let me know, I'll also test it on some VM I have in my position, and

Comment: @molbdnilo I can't access my code right now and also it is a really complex cpp model with too much code to post in order to prove the problem as true, the python code I posted causes the same problem

Comment: @some_random_guy_iam: well there is no problem in saying that the context of this question is a C program but that you managed to exhibit the same problem in a smaller Python script as a [mcve]. But that's not exactly the way your question is written, so molbdnilo's question

Answer (score 0):

SOCK_DGRAM is more resource consuming than SOCK_STREAM, because packet boundaries have to be preserved in order to respect the datagram contract. So depending on the underlying system, the driver could block sender when its internal buffers are full.

But when I tested on my FreeBSD box, I got a slightly different behaviour:

- it accepted 64 packets maximum for small packet size
- it only accepted 3 1024 char packets
- it gave an error instead of blocking

After some more researches, the difference between FreeBSD and Linux is somehow documented since on FB, `send` can fail with ENOBUFS if *The system was unable to allocate an internal buffer* while this error does not exist on Linux man page.

TL/DR: what happens is normal: the internal buffer is full and `send` blocks caller unless you put the socket in non blocking mode. Maybe some kernel parameter would allow to increase the limit of 12 on Linux, but there will always be a limit.

Comment: I dont recall using the word UDP anywhere within my comment

Comment: also I'm specifically using `SOCK_DGRAM` as I want datagrams and not streams within my program, and this occurs within `SOCK_STREAM` as well.. anyways I want to find a way to disable this limitation as I may have more than 12 packets waiting inline to be read